# How to drop a pin on an image instead of a map

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, mapkit

For my current project, I need to drop some pins on a image(NOT a map), and also should be able to click the pin to add some comments to this pin. I wonder if I can use MKAnnotation/MKAnnotationView to do this. I have searched on Internet for a while. I only find tutorials about how to customize MKAnnotation with other images.

If I cannot use MKAnnotation, what should I use? Any tutorials about this will be great helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click on the pin, you should just place a `UIButton` on top the image view. `MKAnnotationView` can only placed within a map view.

Comment: Can UIbutton pop out a callout bubble when I clicked it? Any tutorial or sample code that I can refer to? I am new to iOS programming. Thanks

Comment: No, you have to implement your own callout bubble in this case. You might consider using a `MKMapView` with a `MKAnnotationView` and covering the map with an image `<MKOverlay>` that has `canReplaceMapContent
 = YES`. Then you get the standard callout behavior without actually showing a map.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I will try it during the weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:
     @property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *button;

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   _button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
   UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg" ];
   [_button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(imageTouched:)];
  tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

   [_button addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
   [self.view addSubview:_button];
}

 -(IBAction)imageTouched:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
 {
    CGPoint touchedPoint = [sender locationInView:_button];
    UIButton *pin = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(touchedPoint.x, touchedPoint.y, 10, 10)];
 }
```

You can also link in from the storyboard of course.
Set the image of the button for the state  UIControlStateHighlighted or UIControlStateSelected if you don't want it to flash/show user interaction